# Not binding the IF to any element in Vue

Tags: vue.js

This works:

```
<span v-if="name">
    Hi there, {{ name }}
</span>
```

... but it forces me to use span for the whole text, I just want it on the name variable. In handlebars for example I could do:

```
{{#if name}}
    Hi there, <span>{{ name }}</span>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: You could replace/wrap `span` with `template`. [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/GQMMWG)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [use a template for that](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt).

> we can use `v-if` on a `<template>` element, which serves as an invisible
> wrapper. The final rendered result will not include the `<template>`
> element.

For example:

```
<template v-if="name">
  Hi there, <span>{{ name }}</span>
</template>
```